# Is programming in Visual Basic using Visual studio same as Visual studio enterprise?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-basic

Visual Basic is the language, is there a software with the same name?

Also, in Visual Studio, you can create Visual Basic projects, but they look different than those created using Visual studio enterprise.

Comment: The language is the same, but the tools and features you get are different. Both can create fully functional programs. [This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733713(v=vs.60).aspx) tells you what you will get additionally in Enterprise (Mostly database related utilities).

Comment: There used to be. [Visual Basic 1.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic#Timeline_description) was released in 1991.  [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_97) was first released in 1997.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a misunderstanding: there are two different languages (Visual Basic (VB) and VB.NET) as well as different tools (IDEs - Integrated Developer Environments) like Visual Studio 6 for development with VB and Visual Studio 20xx for development with VB.NET / C#.

The VB is a very old language and will not support, that makes no sense to lern it any more. That is why the Visual Studio 6 isn't the point of interest as well.

You can start with VB.NET or (may be better) with C#, the difference between this two languages is not so big ...
To start with development you can take the free-of-charge version of Visual Studio e.g. [Visual Studio Community* or Visual Studio Express](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-dev-essentials-vs).